# Jquery add class to all previous siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a simple rating system in WordPress.

```
<div id="r1" class="rate_widget"
                             data-post-id="<?php echo $post_id ?>"
                             data-user-id="<?php echo $user_id;  ?>"
                             data-nonce="<?php echo $nonce ?>"
                            >
                            <div data-rating="1" class="ratings_stars"></div>
                            <div data-rating="2" class="ratings_stars"></div>
                            <div data-rating="3" class="ratings_stars"></div>
                            <div data-rating="4" class="ratings_stars"></div>
                            <div data-rating="5" class="ratings_stars"></div>
                            <div class="total_votes">vote data</div>
                        </div>
```

I have three classes

```
1-rating_stars = simply to show star.png
2- ratings_vote = when user hover over stars it turns into yellow
3- ratings_done = After receiving a response star turn into blue.
```

I want to add or remove classes based on the number I receive by Ajax.

Here is the code:

```
$('.ratings_stars').hover(

function() {
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
    },

function() {
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');

    }
);


// This actually records the vote
$('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
    var star = this;
    var widget = $(this).parent();


    var clicked_data = {
    clicked_on : $(star).attr('data-rating'),
    widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id'),
    post_id:$(star).parent().attr('data-post-id') ,
    user_id:$(star).parent().attr('data-user-id') ,
    nonce: $(star).parent().attr('data-nonce'),
    action: 'rating_system'
    };

    console.log(clicked_data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: clicked_data,
        url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
        success: function(INFO) {

            $("div[data-rating = '" + INFO + "']").prevAll().addBack().addClass('ratings_vote');
            $('.rate_widget').find('[data-rating="' + INFO + '"]').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
            $('.rate_widget').find('[data-rating="' + INFO + '"]').nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried these last lines but it doesn't work. But id I run same code in console it works perfectly. INFO is a number from 1 to 5.

```
  $("div[data-rating = '" + INFO + "']").prevAll().addBack().addClass('ratings_vote');
     $('.rate_widget').find('[data-rating="' + INFO + '"]').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
```

Is there any way to work around?

Comment: If running it in console works...Do you have your jQuery wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() {...}`?

Comment: @Tricky12 yes I just did't quote it to make code more readable but it is there. I do receive ajax response in console but unable to add or remove class.

Comment: I'm thinking that you probably don't need `addBack()` in your statement. Other than that, I'm not sure what is causing an issue here. I had luck in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/du77U/

Comment: This is exactly why I am confuse it is working but not in my case

Comment: You can try a `console.log(INFO)` as the first line in your `success: function(INFO)` to make sure it contains what you think it does. If INFO is correct, from what I can tell, everything else looks like it should be working.